# I am sending a cookie from the server-side of my application. Cookie is visible in the response, it does not appear in the browser's cookie tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, httpcookie

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ILK.png)

so here the response cookie is visible when i inspect in network fetch in devtool

but not in cookie tab [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/padU7.png)

and this is my server side code for sending cookies

```
function sendCookie(res, key, value, expDay) {
const exDate = new Date(Date.now() + expDay * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

const cookieOptions = {
path: "/",
expires: exDate,
httpOnly: true,
};

res.cookie(key, value, cookieOptions);
}

module. Exports = { sendCookie };
```

// setting two cookies, the first one without option and second one with options

```
  sendCookie(res,"sessionToken", token, 365)

  return res.status(201).json({
    error: false,
    message: `Welcome Again ${userData.name}`,
    user: userData,
  });
```

// and this is my cors policy

```
app.use(
 cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  credentials: true,
 })
 );
```

i don't know what i'm doing wrong